# Wi-Fi disconnecting after a few minutes

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, realtek

I'm using an old Thinkpad R32 that I found and I installed Debian 8 with LXDE.

I'm using a Wi-Fi dongle which is the RTL8191SU. I installed it using `firmware-linux-nonfree` and `firmware-realtek`. It works for some time but when I try to install something via apt, after around 30 seconds the connection dies.

The weird thing is that on the Network Manager Wicd window the connection still appears to be running.

Nothing appears on `/var/log/syslog` at the moment of the disconnection.

This dongle works perfectly on another computer of mine running the same Debian 8 with LXDE.

If you need addtional information ask me and I'll edit this message as soon as possible.